# RecursionError: I'm looking for a way to reduce the number of the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm looking for an optimization of my code to avoid the following error and make my program more fast.
`maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

I'm looking to execute this code in a docker container. It works perfectly locally on my machine.

I'm looking for a way to reduce the number of loops.

```py
def reidentify(self):
        try:
            # Check if file is re-identify
            self.check_if_dicom_is_reidentify()

            LOGGER.info(f"Anonymization in progress for {self.dirpath_output}")

            # Get patient data
            json_data = json.loads(self.get_patient_data().decode('utf-8'))

            # Re-identification
            archive = zipfile.ZipFile(self.download.dirpath_download, 'r')

            for file in archive.namelist():

                # Check if the file is a dicom
                if not file.endswith('.dcm'):
                    continue

                # Reading dicom file
                dicom_data = io.BytesIO(archive.read(file))
                ds = pydicom.dcmread(dicom_data)

                # Edit Dicom general fields
                for key in json_data['tags']:
                    ds.data_element(key).value = json_data['tags'][key]

                # Edit Dicom series field
                for key in json_data['series']:
                    if key['obfuscated_uid'] != ds.data_element('SeriesInstanceUID').value:
                        continue

                    for tag in key['tags']:
                        ds.data_element(tag).value = key['tags'][tag]

                # Save re-identify dicom
                ds.save_as(f'{self.dirpath_tmp}/{os.path.basename(file)}')

        except Exception as e:
            LOGGER.error(e)
```

This code give the expected result, but I think it's not an optimized method and it's very slow.

EDIT : This is the stack trace

```py
reidentify_1  | 2019-10-17 11:29:53,001] With tag (0010, 1030) got exception: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
reidentify_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
reidentify_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydicom/tag.py", line 30, in tag_in_exception
reidentify_1  |     yield
reidentify_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydicom/filewriter.py", line 541, in write_dataset
reidentify_1  |     write_data_element(fp, dataset.get_item(tag), dataset_encoding)
reidentify_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydicom/filewriter.py", line 485, in write_data_element
reidentify_1  |     writer_function(buffer, data_element)
reidentify_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydicom/filewriter.py", line 338, in write_number_string
reidentify_1  |     val = str(val)
reidentify_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydicom/valuerep.py", line 344, in __str__
reidentify_1  |     return super(DSfloat, self).__str__()
reidentify_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydicom/valuerep.py", line 347, in __repr__
reidentify_1  |     return "\"" + str(self) + "\""
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It would be helpful to have more complete code.  The error message is about recursion depth, but there isn't a function or recursion in the example code.

Comment: You can possibly remove the outer for loop, you never use the `file`

Comment: You right, I added the whole function:

Comment: Still not seeing the recursion ...

Comment: I added the stack trace

Comment: [its a bug](https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/issues/937)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be [fixed](https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/pull/938) but there is no [pypi package](https://pypi.org/project/pydicom/1.3.0/#history) built with that fix.

The origin of this bug is described as follows:

> Python 3.8 removes **str**() from int and float which instead now call
>   object.**str**() which itself defaults to object.**repr**().
>
> DSfloat.**str**(), DSfloat.**repr**() and IS.**repr**() all call the
>   parent class' **str**() which calls the subclass' **repr**() method
>   and so on, which causes a recursion error.
>
> This PR:
>
> ```
> Fixes DSfloat.__str__() by creating a calling repr() instead and removing the " marks.
> Fixes DSfloat.__repr__() by calling the parent class' __repr__() instead of str()
> Fixes IS.__repr__() by implementing IS.__str__() in a similar manner to DSfloat.__str__() and making IS.__repr__() symmetric with
> ```
>
> DSfloat.**repr**()

---

You can try to install it from the git repo directly:

```
pip uninstall pydicom
pip install git+https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom.git
```

Comment: Thanks. Effectively, I used the python 3.8 and now with the 3.7, it's works perfectly :)